# Redirect %2B to +

Tags: url, redirect

I would like to do a 301 Redirect on all %2B in URLs to +. The + in the URL is a urlencoded space. Other sites linking to mine have created %2B in the URL and a valid dynamic page is being created causing duplicate content.

For Example:

http://www.mythicalcreatureslist.com/mythical-creature/Feng%2BHwang

Should redirect to:

http://www.mythicalcreatureslist.com/mythical-creature/Feng+Hwang

I managed to do this with %20 by using this code:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteRule ^(.+)(\s|%20)(.+)$ /$1+$3 [R=301,QSA,L,NE]
```

So tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)(\s|%2B)(.+)$ /$1+$3 [R=301,QSA,L,NE]
```

But that did nothing. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How many '%2B' will in an URL?

Comment: There will be up to 3 '%2B'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code may help you:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}  %2B 
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ %{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA,NE]
```

Comment: Fantastico! This works a real treat. Although the above link with %2B bizarrely links to the old dirty URL (a separate issue) what's important is that the Google Webmaster Tool links under Duplicate Content all point to a URL with + in it. This will really help crackdown on my duplicate content issue. Thanks habeebperwad! :)

Comment: P.S. For others with the same issue: If the above code does not work and you get 500 internal server error, take out the spaces in the square brackets. [R=301,L,QSA,NE]

Comment: @Egan7 I got the issue. But I didn't understand the issue. Should not add spaces there?